# Heroku : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-postgres

We are planning to migrate our **Spring Boot** app from AWS to **Heroku**. As part of which today we tried to deploy our **war** file to Heroku server via cli. The deployment was successful, but on start up we get the error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL`

We are using a **postgresql** database and do use SSL to connect to it. Below is the a portion of **.yml**

```
datasource:
    password: <PASSWORD>
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<HOSTNAME>:5432/<DBNAME>
    username: <USERNAME>
    continue-on-error: true
```

A solution found while searching was to provide `?ssl=false` at the end of the connection URL like shown below:

```
datasource:
    password: <PASSWORD>
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<HOSTNAME>:5432/<DBNAME>?ssl=false
    username: <USERNAME>
    continue-on-error: true
```

But we still get the same error. How do we fix this ? The war works fine in AWS.

Comment: Are you using a Heroku Postgres database? If so, are you using a hobby database or one of their production databases?

Comment: @RangerRanger Currently the database is pointed to the one we are using in AWS itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by changing the connection URL in `.yml` file as shown below:

```
datasource:
    password: <PASSWORD>
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<HOSTNAME>:5432/<DBNAME>?sslmode=disable
    username: <USERNAME>
    continue-on-error: true
```

Can find more info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java)

Comment: Disabling SSL isn't super advisable.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks! Will make sure to enable it in production.